# Express Flash message doesn't work with Axios but works in Postman. Why is that?

Tags: node.js, axios, passport.js, express-session, flash-message

I couldn't figure out why my flash message wasn't available when testing a bad password login. Finally I figured it out; flash doesn't work with Axios.

**Why is it that `flash-connect` doesn't work with Axios but it works with Postman?** I'm a noob with sessions, so I think it may have something to do with sessions.

I used Node.js, Express.js, Passport.js

Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/DashBarkHuss/859959b5979913f12da6bec2682be58b).

How to recreate using the [gist](https://gist.github.com/DashBarkHuss/859959b5979913f12da6bec2682be58b):

1. Save each file in a project folder
2. `npm install`
3. `npm start`

You'll see axios log to the console: *"Error from Flash Message: **undefined**"*. The flash message is missing.

If you use Postman and post to `http://localhost:3300/login` with the body `{ "email":"test@test.com", "password": "paskword" }` you get the correct flash message: *Error from Flash Message: **invalid password.***